# Interactive map with regions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My friend and I are trying to making an interactive map the goes to a new page based on the region clicked. We might try image mapping via dreamweaver but want something with a little more flair/interaction ie: glowing on hover, highlights, ect.

Comment: Try SVG's, use Photoshop or more preferably Illustrator to draw your maps by region, then just position each region using fixed positions.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [KineticJS.](http://kineticjs.org)  It's an HTML5 Canvas library that allows you to redraw shapes, apply effects, tell when you click on shapes, etc.  You can use the `on` function to go to a new page when you click on it, and there's probably something for the glowing.

Answer (score 0):

I use http://jvectormap.com/

There are maps for lots of countries and you can add your own quite easily.

Here's an example: http://jvectormap.com/examples/world-gdp/

Answer (score 0):

For me [imagemapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/) is one of the best for this task, have multiple functions and a well documented page